# Replacing select->option by retrieving info from textfile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get rid of option value and retrieve info from text file. So when I later want to add SP4, i can just go to text file and add SP4 like below. So that I don't have to go through the code to update whatever i want to add.

servicePackinfo.txt
SP1
SP2
SP3
SP4

```
<select name="servicePack">
   <option value="SP1">SP1</option>
   <option value="SP2">SP2</option>
   <option value="SP3">SP3</option>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Bare in mind that the file servicePackinfo.txt must be in the same directory if you will just copy and paste this example.

```
<select name="servicePack" id="servicePack"></select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('servicePackinfo.txt', function(data) {
        var options = data.split(' ');
        for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++)
        {
           $('<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>').appendTo('#servicePack');        
        }
    });
});

</script>
```